# No form will be shown?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

Here I have the following models

Customer
Book
Book_Manager

My association are has follow

```
BookManager
belongs_to :customer
Customer
has_many :book_managers, :dependent => :destroy
```

Book isn't required at this stage

This is based on the nested model form from Railscasts but I can't seem to see why it doesn't work. The application should work has follow

A customer goes into customer#edit then see BookManagers (the last one created) if any. If not then simply see blank and a form to allow him to create a new book_manager which will in the future have a book associated. But i am not at that stage.

Here the customer controller

```
def edit
    @customer = Customer.find(params[:id])
    @bookmanager = BookManager.first_or_create
end
```

The render file his has follow

```
<h3>Book</h3>
<div><%= render 'book_managers/form' %></div>
```

Here the _form.html.erb file in book_managers

```
<% form_for (@bookmanager) do |f| %>  
  <div class="field">  
    <%= f.label :customer_id %><br />  
    <%= f.text_field :customer_id %>  
  </div>  
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>  
<% end %>
```

I know it get render properly, if i put scrap words in it, i will see them outside the form. But i am not to sure if bookmanager is actually empty,nil or properly set up

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6189728/render-form-partial-in-a-different-controller-not-nested

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `<% form_for (@bookmanager) do |f| %>` to

Rails 3:

```
<%= form_for (@bookmanager) do |f| %>
```

Rails 2:

```
<%- form_for (@bookmanager) do |f| %>
```

You need a `-` (Rails 2) or `=` (Rails 3) after the `<%`.

Comment: Thanks it works, what would be the best way for my controller?